# AJAX/PHP Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: php, ajax

I have this ajax script which presents me with this error, this script and link a form intended for an email send the ajax script allows not to reload the page when sending an email and retrieves the data from my bootstrap form do you have a solution?

Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined /!\

```
$('#send_email').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = {
    email: $('#email').val(),
    name: $('#name').val(),
    objet: $('#firstname').val(),
    message: $('#message').val()
  };
  $.ajax({
    url: "mail.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(data2) {
      $('#js_alert_succes').css({
        'display': 'block'
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#js_alert_succes').css({
          'display': 'none'
        });
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#name').val("");
        $('#object').val("");
        $('#message').val("")
      }, 3000);

      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(data) {
      $('#js_alert_danger').css({
        'display': 'block'
      });
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#js_alert_danger').css({
          'display': 'none'
        });
        $('#email').val("");
        $('#name').val("");
        $('#object').val("");
        $('#message').val("")
      }, 3000);

      console.log(data)

    }
  });
});
```

here the php script for sending email

```
   <?php
if($_POST){
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $object = $_POST['objet'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $name <$email>\r\nReply-to : $name <$email>\nX-Mailer:PHP";
  $subject="$objet";
  $destinataire="postmaster@arrowsecurite.com";   
  $body="$message";
  if(mail($destinataire,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
    $response['status'] = 'success';
    $response['msg'] = 'votre email est envoyé';
  } else {
    $response['status'] = 'error';
    $response['msg'] = 'votre email na pas été envoyé';
  }
  echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: the error is line 41 from the console

Comment: the error makes no reference to the field `firstname` which you explicitly expect to appear in the POSTed data. Have you shown the actual code? Which is line 41?

Comment: line 41 corresponds to a `console.log(data)`

Comment: you have no idea please ?

Comment: Try adding dataType:"Json", to the $ajax and console.log(data2) to follow up on the response

Comment: There's two `console.log(data)` in the code, which one is it? The one in `success` or the one in `error`?

Comment: Either way, I don't see how you could get that error. `data` is the variable you set right before the `$.ajax` call, and nothing changes that.

Comment: same error with dataType:"Json", to the $ajax and console.log(data2)